# argument errors when using using Python to access to aws ecr

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-ecr

here is the function:

```
def sh(*command, read_output=False, **kwargs):
    command_text = " ".join(command)
    print(f"\t> {command_text}")
    try:
        if read_output:
            return check_output(command, **kwargs).decode("utf8")
        else:
            check_call(command, **kwargs)
    except CalledProcessError as failure:
        print(
            f'ERROR: "{command_text}" command reported failure! Return code {failure.returncode}.'
        )
        sys.exit(failure.returncode)
```

I'm trying to use this function to get aws erc get-login first, then use that returned login command to login to aws erc. here is my codes:

```
result = sh('aws', 'ecr', 'get-login', '--no-include-email', read_output=True)
re = result.split()
sh(re)
```

then I get error:

```
command_text = " ".join(command)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

I think the `sh` function expect arguments something like `('docker', 'login', '-u', 'AWS', '-p'...), but how can I achieve this?

Comment: instead of `sh(re)`, I can use `sh(re[0], re[1], re[2], re[3], re[4], re[5], re[6])` and it run successfully. But this is definitely not good coding. so what's the idiomatic way to do this? Thanks

Comment: `sh( *re )` ???

Comment: @furas that works. so what's the magic of using `*` before the list variable?

Comment: it unpacks list/tuple so function treats it as many arguments, not as single list/tuple. Similar way works `**` with dictionary and named arguments.

Comment: other method is to use `sh(command,..)` without `*` so you can send it as list/tuple. You can even if you sends list or string `if isinstance(command, str): command_text = command elif isinstance(command, list): command_text = " ".join(command)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `*` to unpack list/tuple and function get it as many arguments

```
sh( *re )
```

Or you can remove `*` from `*command` in definiton

```
def sh(command, ...)
```

and then you can send it only as list/tuple

```
sh( re )
```

but you can also check if `command` is `list` or `string`

```
if isinstance(command, str): 
    command_text = command 
elif isinstance(command, list, tuple): 
    command_text = " ".join(command)
```

so then you can send it directly as one string.

```
sh( 'aws ecr get-login --no-include-email' )
```

or list with strings

```
sh( ['aws', 'ecr', 'get-login', '--no-include-email'] )
```

---

BTW: Similar way works `**` with dictionary and named arguments

```
def fun(a=0, b=0, c=0):
    print('a:', a)
    print('b:', b)
    print('c:', c)

data = {'b':2}

fun(**data)
```